# Laravel 5 Validation - validating the sum of 2 fields

Tags: laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5's [Form Request Validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation) feature to validate a form input.

In my form, I have 2 fields `num_adults` and `num_children`.

I need to ensure that the sum of both fields do not exceed a certain value.

What I've tried is in the `rules()` function of my validation file, I used `merge()` to artificially add a new input value that is the sum of both `num_adults` and `num_children`.

```
$this->merge([
    'max_persons' => $this->input('num_adults') + $this->input('num_children') 
]);
```

And then in the rules array returned,

```
$rules = [
    'num_adults' => 'integer|max:2',
    'num_children' => 'integer|max:1',
    'max_persons' => 'integer|max:2',
];
```

The validation works fine for `num_adults` and `num_children`. But `max_persons` seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might skip the array merge and have my rules like:

```
$rules = [
    'num_adults' => 'integer|max:'.(2-$this->get('num_children', 0)) ,
    'num_children' => 'integer|max:'.(2-$this->get('num_adults', 0))
];
```

2 being the maximum permitted value.

On the other hand, the approach that you've started gives you a little more flexibility on the error messages.

The validator already has the values before you update the array, so it doesn't know about your addition. You could add a validator method to your request object to merge in your values a little earlier in the process.

```
public function validator(Factory $factory)
{
    $this->merge([
        'max_persons' => $this->input('num_adults') + $this->input('num_children') 
    ]);

    return $factory->make(
        $this->all(),
        $this->rules(),
        $this->messages()
    );
}
```